# Angular 2: How to access Template Input Variables in Structural Directives

Tags: angular

How do I access [Template Input Variables](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html#template-input-variable) in my own Custom Structural Directive?

```
@Directive({
   selector: "[myCustomDirective]"
})
export class MyCustomDirective {
}
```

The documentation says that `A template input variable is a variable whose value you can reference within a single instance of the template.`

```
<div *myCustomDirective="let visible = true"></div>
```

I know that the template now has an input called `let-visible` but how do I access it?

------------------- EDIT -------------------

I want to be able to accept multiple Inputs using the structural directive. Is that possible?

I want one Input to be assigned to `myCustomDirective` itself and one to `visible` thats why I was trying to use the `let visible` syntax like `ngFor` does.

Comment: You want to access the value of "visible" inside your custom structural directive?

Comment: Yes. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You have to also import `Input` at the top of your directive module.

```
@Directive({
   selector: "[myCustomDirective]"
})
export class MyCustomDirective {
  @Input()
  set myCustomDirective(isVisible: boolean): void {
    // do something with isVisible
  }
}
```

Usage of directive.

```
<div *myCustomDirective="true"></div>
```

Comment: But I did mention that I am creating my own custom Structural Directive. Thats why it leads with the `*` character.

Comment: @takeradi - I removed the comment but I will leave the rest as is considering its applicable to either type of directive.

Comment: So your answer is not valid for my case. Also I am not sure if you can use a `[visible]` input on a `div`. Div is not a custom component so how can you assign an `Input` to it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below:

```
            import { Directive,Input,...} from '@angular/core';
            @Directive({
               selector: "[myCustomDirective]"
            })
            export class MyCustomDirective {

            //using the Input decorator, we can accept the value of the property (in our case, it is myCustomDirective)and //use it inside our directive class.
             @Input('myCustomDirective')
              private visible: boolean;

              //console.log(this.visible);

            }

            // Use it, maybe like this:
            <div *myCustomDirective="true"></div>
```